# snapd fails to start with sshfs mount in fstab

Tags: 16.04, snap

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Latest version of snapd fails to start if /etc/fstab contains an sshfs mount.

```
sshfs#ftpUser@server.domain.com:/home/jail/user/files/ /media/mediadrive fuse defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,port=22,reconnect,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_ftpUser 0 0
```

snapd throws the following errors in /var/log/syslog

```
Apr  3 22:36:57 user-desktop snapd[9759]: 2018/04/03 22:36:57.832306 backend.go:104: cannot determine if NFS is in use: cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 1
Apr  3 22:36:57 user-desktop snapd[9759]: 2018/04/03 22:36:57.835483 system_key.go:117: cannot determine nfs usage in generateSystemKey: cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 1
Apr  3 22:36:57 user-desktop snapd[9759]: 2018/04/03 22:36:57.835499 helpers.go:115: error trying to compare the snap system key: cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 1
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop snapd[9759]: 2018/04/03 22:36:58.631222 system_key.go:117: cannot determine nfs usage in generateSystemKey: cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 1
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop snapd[9759]: error: cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 1
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop systemd[1]: snapd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr  3 22:36:58 user-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
```

Commenting out the sshfs line allows snapd to start. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the fstab entry for sshfs fixed the issue.

```
ftpUser@server.domain.com:/home/jail/user/files/ /media/mediadrive fuse.sshfs defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,port=22,reconnect,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_ftpUser 0 0
```

For some reason, snap does not like the format beginning with sshfs#

Comment: this was fixed in 2018, i believe, so # in NFS source is now fine.